# Reset (not respawn) a dungeon/area to my current level

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a console command to reset (not respawn) a dungeon/area. I mean that when you enter an area it is locked to your level at that point (within certain constraints). I want to completely reset an area so that I can enter it again (now at a higher level) and have its inhabitants/contents set to my current level.

I know how to respawn an area using the console but is it possible to reset an area?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? You mentioned you managed to respawn an area, but not reset it.

Comment: I can't find a console command that might reset the area - so have tried nothing else yet. I was hoping someone else had tried and found a solution. Thanks :) .

Comment: Did you try `resetinterior <cellid>` yet?

Comment: Thanks but I do not believe this works. I did a quick test. I went into Shimmermist Cave as level 20. Populated by Falmer (no suffix) and a Frostbite Spider. I levelled up to 50. I reset the cave using the resetinterior command (both zones) and went back. It was now inhabited by a Skeever and Falmer (no suffix).

Comment: Can you repeat it using `getlevel` while targetting the NPC with mouse click?

Comment: @3ventic The `resetinterior` command is for objects only: it resets the location/existence of the contents of the cells to what appears in the ESP/ESM files. It doesn't touch game variables attached to the cell.

Comment: Thanks SevenSidedDie - do you know if there is a way to change the variables that link your level on first entry to each location please?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for clarification, I only (quickly) checked the description in uesp wiki.

Comment: @3ventic Yeah, the description doesn't make it obvious if you don't have any experience with modding those things. :) I suspect there simply isn't a command or tool to do this yet. It's a new engine feature, and BethSoft often overlooks integrating new engine features thoroughly into the console commands. It's also something modders aren't particularly interested in, it seems, so there has been no reverse engineering to build a tool to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple here, No, you can only reset. The only way to do this would be to create your own mod and inject it into memory so get around this;however, the mobs would not dynamically adjust to your level unless it was already setup to do so.

Answer (score -2):

No, how unlikely it sounds it is not possible.